# Poisson distribution example

Tags: probability

> The number of traﬃc accidents occurring on any given day in Coralville
> is Poisson distributed with mean 5. The probability that any such
> accident involves an uninsured driver is 0.25, independent of all
> other such accidents. Calculate the probability that on a given day in
> Coralville there are no traﬃc accidents that involve an uninsured
> driver.

#### Try

If we call $X$ the number of accidents and $A$ the event that driver is uninsured, then we ought to find $P( \{X=0 \} |A )$. We know $P(X=0) = e^{-5}$ and so

$$ P(X=0) = P( \{X=0 \} |A ) P(A) + P( \{X=0 \} |A^c) P(A^c) $$

Where $P(A) = 0.25$ and $P(A^c) = 0.75$.

My question is, how can we compute $P( \{X=0 \} |A^c )$ ? that is the only piece I need to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong formulation, because *each* accident either involves an uninsured driver or not, and you could have accidents with insured drivers that don't correspond to the event you're measuring. The right way to think about this is to imagine parallel Poisson processes of "accidents involving uninsured drivers" and "accidents not involving uninsured drivers", and measure the probability that the former process never jumps from $0$ to $1$.

You can do this because under these assumptions, the rate of the former process is just $0.25 \cdot 5$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have set up the problem correctly.  What you want is the sum over n of n accidents where in each case there were no uninsured drivers.
$P=e^{-5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5^{n} \times .75^{n}}{n!}=e^{-1.25}=0.2865..$

Comment: This is an equivalent way to solve the problem, essentially using the total probability formula and conditioning on the total number of accidents.